# Unique decentralized ID systems

Tags: voting

We are all familiar with the standard decentralized ID system, the web of trust, e.g. for PGP keys. However, normal web of trust systems are unable to guarantee uniqueness — there's no practical limit on the number of public keys I can register under aliases that appear to be seperate individuals. These systems are thus unsuited for applications like voting where uniqueness is paramount. My question is: are there any ID systems that are both decentralized, i.e. do not rely on trust in a single individual or group, and at the same time guarantee with high probability that any two given IDs belong to unique individuals?

Comment: you can generate IDs that are unlikely to be repeated, at least less likely than mathematical chance alone, but if you can't know how many IDs there are or who made them, it's hard to correlate any two